# vb.net - receiving hex data over serial interface

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I do have a device, which I communicate with over the serial Interface.

The communication is done in hex, so I send hex and I do receive hex.

Example: if I send "AA 00 03 89 18 0A 98 BB" the device reports back with "AA 00 02 00 80 82 BB".

My aim is to get a hand on the return value in an human readable way, respecively as a string.

The sending works fine, however the receiving is the part where I struggle hard and where I need help.

---

**The sending part:**

This is the part where I define the command to send:

```
Public Class ClassRfidWrapper

    Public Function Command(ByVal theCommand As String) As Byte()

        'Versuche.
        Try

            If theCommand = "SetBuzzer" Then
                Dim bytes() As Byte = {&HAA, &H0, &H3, &H89, &H18, &HA, &H98, &HBB}
                Return bytes
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
            Console.WriteLine("Class -> ClassRfidWrapper, Method -> SendCommand, Error -> " & ex.Message)
        End Try

        Return Nothing
    End Function

End Class
```

This is the part where I send the hex message to the device:

Public Sub MySendSerialData(ByVal data As Byte())

```
'Versuche.
Try
    If MyCheckIfSerialIsConnected() = True Then

        'Mitteilung.
        Main.MessageObject.MyMessage("message sent to device: ", Bytes_To_String2(data), 3)

        'Log [LogWrapperToDevice]
        Main.LogObject.MyLog(Bytes_To_String2(data), "LogWrapperToDevice")

        SerialInterface.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
    Console.WriteLine("Class -> ClassSerialInterface, Method -> MySendSerialData, Error -> " & ex.Message)
End Try
```

End Sub

Do the sending:

```
SerialInterfaceObject.MySendSerialData(RfidWrapperObject.Command("SetBuzzer"))
```

Function to convert Hex to string:

```
Public Function Bytes_To_String2(ByVal bytes_Input As Byte()) As String
    Dim strTemp As New StringBuilder(bytes_Input.Length * 2)
    For Each b As Byte In bytes_Input
        strTemp.Append(Conversion.Hex(b))
    Next
    Return strTemp.ToString()
End Function
```

---

**The receiving part:**

This is where I have the problems

```
Public Shared Sub DataReceivedHandler(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    Dim sp As SerialPort = CType(sender, SerialPort)
    Dim data As String = sp.ReadExisting()
    'Mitteilung.
    Main.MessageObject.MyMessage("incoming serial data: ", CStr(data), 3)
    'Log [LogDeviceToWrapper]
    Main.LogObject.MyLog(CStr(data), "LogDeviceToWrapper")
End Sub
```

The problem is, I get garbage...

I understand, that .ReadExisting is the wrong way, as it interprets the received data as string, so I need an example code, of how to receive and convert the data to a byte array containing hex code, which I can subsequently convert to a string with my function Bytes_To_String2

Thanks for your help

Comment: I agree, that hex as a string isnt very nice to read, still I can use it for debugging purposes and comparison purposes - which is all I want to do at this time. The problem is not the conversion, I have already a function doing this for me. The problem is how to get the data from the serial interface in an byte array containing the hex code? Must have something to do with this: Dim data As String = sp.ReadExisting()

Comment: in other words the problem is in the DataReceivedHandler of the serial interface...

Comment: You cannot use ReadExisting().  You have to read one byte at a time until you get &HBB.  Assuming that the device protocol uses it as the end-of-message marker.  And to do it properly you also have to throw away bytes until you get &HAA, it ensures you are in sync with the device.  BitConverter.ToString() gives you something that you can display.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do this correct?

Comment: You are sending a string, so I assume you are also receiving a string. If you expect "AA" to be received, then this is the string "AA" so in byte it should be 0x41 0x41 (or 65 65) which is [the number of the ascii character A](https://www.bing.com/search?q=ascii+table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the response buffer as a byte array.

```
Public Shared Sub DataReceivedHandler(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    Dim sp As SerialPort = CType(sender, SerialPort)

    Dim respSize As Integer = sp.BytesToRead

    Dim respBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(respSize - 1)

    comport.Read(respBuffer, 0, respSize)

    ' Convert to string and additional processing ...
End Sub
```